# How to name different versionName and versionCode for multiple apks of the same application?

Tags: android, android-version, multiple-apk, android-multiple-apk

I have one published application on Google play with VersionName=1.0 and VersionCode=1.Now I want to upload a different apk for the same application which will support only tablets.

Rules on developer android site say that different apks must have different versionCodes.So I will give VersionCode=2 to the new apk.Will I also have to change the VersionName which is 1.0 for the already uploaded apk?

Also If I upload new apk with VersionName 1.0 and VersionCode 2, Will the users who already downloaded the published application get the upgrade notification of the application.I just want to gain knowledge about the upgrade scenarios and version naming in multiple apks publishing.

Please dont post the link of developer android website.I have read all the rules.I want guidance from one who has implemented multiple apks for the application on Google Play.

Comment: If your new app is configured to target a different range of devices, they will not receive a notification with a new version, otherwise they will.

Comment: @zozelfelfo - ok.Can I give versionName equal to 1.0 as that of the already published apk?

Comment: AFAIK the only thing that needs to change is versionNumber, I have multiple apks (but only one active) with the same versionName, so I think it will be possible

Comment: @zozelfelfo - So I can have two apks uploaded with different versionCode but same VersionName(1.0).Right? Also If I want to update just one apk(that supports tablets) I can change the versionName and versionCode of that apk and only those users who have downloaded that apk will receive the update notification?

Comment: That's the theory :), you dont even need to change the versionName, the versionNumber is the mandatory one :)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to create multiple flavors of your app. One for normal app and one for tablets.

In the `build.gradle` file you will be able to specify the versions like this:

```
productFlavors {
    phone {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "com.default.package.phone"
    }
    tablet {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        applicationId "com.default.package.tablet"
    }
}
```

You can also specify different package names for these flavors if you want the user to be able to install both of these apps at the same time.

Comment: I dont want to give different packages for different apk.Also I will give different screen-support configuration in manifest file so user will be able to download the apk which is supported in his device without knowing the nitty-gritties of the application